# Synchronizing parcelable state between Activities?

Tags: android, parcelable, data-synchronization

I have `Parcelable` object that holds a `query` and `offset` to web API.

Then I have two Activities:

`Activity` A with a list and `Activity` B with a `ViewPager`. User navigates from `Activity` A to B, and `Parcelable` is passed in `Intent`. In `Activity` A query is persisted using `onSaveInstanceState`. (initial `offset` is 0 )

Inside `Activity` B activity user can swipe and offset can be increased. (`offset` increased to 20 )

Then user can navigate back to `Acitvity` A with list. In `Activity` A query is restored from `savedInstanceState`. ('offset` is 0 but should be 20 )

What is the best way to maintain such offset state between those two Activities? I want to avoid saving it to shared preferences.

Comment: Is it possible to replace your two Activities by two fragments? Then you could save your offset to the one Activity that contains the two fragments.

Comment: Sounds like storing the value in shared preferences or in a database would be a better solution here.  I would probably just go with shared preferences if it's just one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start Activity B '[forResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)', and when navigating back to Acivity A, set the result including the offset, so you can access it in Activity A in `onAcivityResult()`
And refresh the value accordingly...